# Facebook app submission for approval with extended permission in php

Tags: facebook, publish-actions

I an using facebook app in my website with extended permissions like **read_stream**, **publish_actions**.

But when I look to submit for approval there i see a section *"Add items for submission"*. But I could not found *"publish_actions"* permission and some other permissions there.

Actually When any user login then I am asking for *"email and read_stream"*.
But after login I need to take extended permissions on certain button click.

My permissions are:

- email
- offline_access
- public_profile
- user_friends
- user_status
- read_stream
- publish_actions

So please suggest me How can I submit my app for approval and with which permissions. Should I mentioned all permissions in facebook app approval process ??

Comment: You will not get `read_stream` granted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should request review of all permissions that you want to use. When your app is in development mode, you (being Admin, Developer or Tester on the app) can use all the permissions available. When your app is in live mode, it can only use the permissions that have been approved. Even if you pass in more permissions to the Login Dialog, it will only show those that have approved for your app by Facebook.

As CBroe mentions, the `read_stream` permission is very restricted. From the permissions submission dialog:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.